# Newline In Email Using Paste Command

Tags: arrays, shell, email, paste

I am using paste command in the mail that I am sending using shell script.
The output on the console looks perfect but the output in the mail is not in the same format. How do I make the format in the mail too same as in the console. The example below is just an example. The arrays values are dynamic. So I cannot use html table.

```
#!/bin/bash

BASETABLE[0]="ABC"
BASETABLE[1]="XYZ"
WORKFLOW[0]="123"
WORKFLOW[1]="789"

paste -d' ' <(printf "\n") <(printf "\n%-12.12s\n" "${BASETABLE[@]}") <(printf "\n%s\n" "${WORKFLOW[@]}")

echo "Test" `paste -d' ' <(printf "\n") <(printf "\n%-12.12s\n" "${BASETABLE[@]}") <(printf "\n%s\n" "${WORKFLOW[@]}")` | mail -s "Test" user@xyz.com
```

Outout on Console:

```
ABC          123

XYZ          789
```

Output in Mail:

```
ABC 123 XYZ 789
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your use of the `echo` statement.  `echo` will not preserve newlines in an unquoted string.  For example, if I have a variable containing a newline:

```
my_variable="This is
a test"
```

If I echo it without quotes, newlines will be transformed into spaces:

```
$ echo $my_variable
This is a test
```

But if I quote the variable, newlines will be preserved:

```
$ echo "$my_variable"
This is
a test
```

So you can get the output you want by simply moving the closing quote in your `echo` statement, so that it becomes:

```
echo "Test `paste -d' ' <(printf "\n") <(printf "\n%-12.12s\n" "${BASETABLE[@]}") <(printf "\n%s\n" "${WORKFLOW[@]}")`"
```

This will output:

```
Test
 ABC          123

 XYZ          789
```

Instead of:

```
Test ABC 123 XYZ 789
```